# Multiple wildcards in Laravel resource routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I declared resource route like below

> Route::resource('{slug}/user','ManageUsersController');

This gives me a route

> {slug}/user/{id}

where slug is the slug of a company name and id is the specific id of user.

In view, I declared anchor tag : `<a href=user/{!! $user->id!!}`>User`</a>`
This directs me to the function `show` in ManageUserController

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        return $id;
    }
```

But the return result is the `slug`, not the the id of the user. My URL is `project/company-name/user/5`

Where did i go wrong ? how can i get the user ID in return rather than the slug ?

-thanx

Comment: try to take 2 parameter in show method show($slug,$id) and return both them to check.May be it will work.

Comment: And, that's the answer. Thank you. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to catch both slug and id in your method,so your method will like

```
public function show($slug, $id)
{
    //for slug
    return $slug;
    //for id
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass both parameters to your controller method, because Laravel will consider the first parameter to be the first parameter in the route (which would be your slug).